# How to create P2P videocall app using webRTC with kotlin. It should connect two mobile devices with peer to peer video calling capabilities

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create it without server setup P2P videocall app using webRTC with kotlin. It should connect two mobile devices with peer to peer video calling capabilities.